# Updating URL for page filters in web app: Hash or History API?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a web application where a large set of data can be filtered using JavaScript. When a user selects filters, I want to update the URL of the page to reflect the selected filters so that the user can share that URL with someone else, and that person can load the page and my app will apply the same filters. *I don't have a need for the back buttons in the browser to cycle thru the previous filters that were selected*.

I think I have two approaches here:

1. I can create a representation of the filters and add them to the fragment of the current page via `window.location.hash`. I can parse them on page load to see if there are any already set.
2. I can create a representation of the filters as query string params, and manipulate the URL using the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). I would use the replaceState method.

Is there a reason to chose one over the other? Again, I want to emphasize that I'm not concerned with any routing or browser history manipulation. I just want to provide a way for someone to put certain params in the URL that my JS code will parse and apply as the filters.

Comment: There are other options, including using a `data URL`

Comment: I’m currently implementing this using $route query and watch it for changes

Answer (score 0):

Using the Vue router and may be also vuex for state management should help you save some time. There is also a little helper library for url encoding / decoding --> qs.

To your question "history vs hash": that depends on your application, the system which hosts the application (e.g. part of a content management system with its own url handling) and the meaning of the params.

History mode generates better looking paths and features some more control, as long as you stay in your application. But: as your path segments have no identifiers, the sort order matters.

Scenario: You have an application which can have three params:

/value1/value2/value3 means something else as /value1/value3/value2

With a query string you don't need to take care about sort order, as every value has its key:
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3 is the same as key1=value1&key3=value3&key2=value2

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Indeed, I don't need to use path segments for this, the order of the params is not important. The system which hosts this little JS application is a PHP CMS. So that CMS is responsible for delivering the initial page contents and the JS code. The query strings or hashes should not affect the application at all.